# Finding the middle of a list - Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I'm new to haskell and I need some help. I wrote something very simple which calculates the sum of the squares of a list of numbers.

```
sumOfSquares:: [Integer] -> Integer
sumOfSquares []       = 0
sumOfSquares (x:xs)   = x*x + sumOfSquares xs
```

so sumOfSquares [1..10] would be 385.

I'm struggling with how to find the middle of the list and apply 'sumOfSquares' to only the middle element and everything above it.

So using the above example, i'd only want to find out the sum of the squares of 5-10 and ignore the first half of the list.

I was thinking of using splitAt, am I along the right lines? Am i missing something obvious?

Comment: `splitAt` would be fine, you'll have to calculate the length first though.  This would be somewhat inefficient, but not noticeable for 10 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `drop` as in this example:

```
sumOfSquares:: [Integer] -> Integer
sumOfSquares []       = 0
sumOfSquares (x:xs)   = x*x + sumOfSquares xs

sumOfSecondHalf xs = sumOfSquares $ drop len xs
    where len = length xs `div` 2 - 1
```

For your information, this:

```
sumOfSquares $ drop len xs
```

is the same as:

```
sumOfSquares (drop len xs)
```

Moreover, your `sumOfSquares` function can be rewritten this way:

```
square :: Integer -> Integer
square x = x * x

sumOfSquares:: [Integer] -> Integer
sumOfSquares = sum . map square
```

where `map` applies the function square to each element of a list and `sum` returns the sum of a list.

and this:

```
sumOfSquares = sum . map square
```

is the same as:

```
sumOfSquares xs = sum (map square xs)
```